# Let $f(n) = n^{(n+1)}$ can we say that $f(n)$ is $O(n^n)$

Tags: asymptotics

Let $f(n) = n^{(n+1)}$ can we say that $f(n)$ is $O(n^n)$?

To solve this problem I am using the Big-Oh definition:

We must find $c_1$ and $N_0$ such that $f(n) \leq C_1 \times n^2$ for $n \geq N_0$

**My Attempt:**

I say that we cannot say that $f(n)$ is $O(n^n)$ because $n^{(n+1)} $ will always be greater than $n^n$ for $(n \geq 1)$.

$ n^{(n+1)} \leq n^n$ for $(n \geq 1) \rightarrow$ This is false

Am I on the right track? I'm not sure if what i've written is enough of a proof.

**EDIT: I've gotten a little further**

I let $f(n) = n^{n+1}$ and $g(n)=n^n$.

Now, $N_0 \geq 1$ and $C_1 = 2$

Now, $n^{n+1} \leq 2 \times n^n$ for $n \geq 1 \rightarrow$ This is false

However,

I let $f(n) = n^{n+1}$ and $g(n)=n^n$.

Now, $N_0 \geq 1$ and $C_1 = 2$

Now, $n^{n+1} \leq 2 \times n^n$ for $n \geq 2 \rightarrow$ This is True

Is my truth enough to be represented as a proof?

**Edit # 2**

$n^{n+1} \leq C\times n^n$

$n^n \times n^1 \leq C \times n^n$

$n^1 \leq c$

Therefore, $N_0 = 1$ and $C_1 \geq 1$

$n^{n+1} \leq 1 \times n^n$ for $n \geq 1$

---

I also have another problem: Let $f(n) = n!$. Prove $f(n)$ is $O(n^n)$

**My Attempt:**

I feel as if the answer is simply:

$n! \leq n^n$ for $(n \geq 1)$

I can prove this using a graph, but do I need to show more math?

The blue line is $n^n$, and the red line is $n!$

[image]

Comment: Not the right track. Assume there is a constant $C$ such that $n^{n+1}\leq Cn^n$ for all larger enough $n$. Then $n\leq C$ for those $n$.

Comment: For $n!$ you can use [Stirling's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Stirling formula is way overkill here.

Comment: @logarithm Thanks I think I see. I need to determine the value of the constant, $C$ which causes $n^n$ to be greater than $n^{n+1}$. I will be working on this. I plan on having $n \geq 1$

Comment: It's not "value of the constant". You need to show that for *any* constant $n^{n + 1} > C n^n$ for arbitrarily large $n$.

Comment: There isn't. Such constant would need to be larger than all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: That brings me back to my original thought that $n^{n+1} $ cannot be $O(n^n)$

Comment: You may have $O$ confused with $\Omega$.

Comment: @Qudit I edited my question to make more sense. Thank you

Comment: @logarithm I think I've finally understood what you're talking about in edit # 2

Comment: $n^{n+1}$ is not equal to $n^n+n^1$. It is equal to $n^n\cdot n$.

Comment: Thank you I've updated the solution with that fix.